# Unable to get space between the 2 rows

Tags: html, css

I need some space between the 2 rows. When I use `<br/>` nothing happens, If i use padding, nothing happens. If i don't use block styles in the div's only the text moves down with padding and br. The images just don't move.

```
<h1>The Team</h1>
    <style type="text/css">
        .photo {
            padding-right: 5%;
            width: 20%;
            float: left;
        }
       .intro {
            width: 60%;
            float: right;
            padding-right: 10%;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
       }
       .name {
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: bold;
            line-height: 0px;
            padding-top: 0px;
            color: #000000;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
       }
       .introduction {
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
            font-weight: regular;
            line-height: 20px;
            color: #000000;
       }
       .italics {
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-style: italic;
            line-height: 0px;
            padding-top: 0px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
            line-height: 0px;
            color: #000000;
      }
      td {
          padding: 0px;
      }
      tr {
          padding=bottom: 40px;
      }
</style>

<div display="block">
   <div display="block">
      <img class="photo" alt="Taxeeta, Founder and CTO" src="http://localhost/taxeeta/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/dummy-picture1.png" />
   </div>
   <div class="intro" display="inline">
      <h4 class="name">Siddharth</h4>
      <h4 class="italics">Founder, CTO</h4>
      <h4 class="introduction">Having invested bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla .</h4>
   </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div display="block">
    <div display="block">
       <img class="photo" alt="Taxeeta, Mentor" src="http://localhost/taxeeta/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/dummy-picture1.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="intro" display="inline">
       <h4 class="name">Zubin</h4>
       <h4 class="italics">Advisor</h4>
       <h4 class="introduction">Zubin is a bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla .</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

As of now it looks like as below :
[image: Taxeeta web page, the team]

Comment: could you create a fiddle for that or make it more clear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your floats. Float takes the element out of the normal docment flow.

Add a class to you "staff" div and use that to clear the floats.

**HTML**

```
<div class="staff">    
    <img class="photo" alt="Taxeeta, Founder and CTO" src="http://placehold.it/350x350" />    
    <div class="intro" >
        <h4 class="name">Siddharth</h4>      
        <h4 class="italics">Founder, CTO</h4>
        <div class="introduction">Having invested bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla .</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="staff">
    <img class="photo" alt="Taxeeta, Mentor" src="http://placehold.it/350x350" />    
    <div class="intro">
    <h4 class="name">Zubin</h4>
    <h4 class="italics">Advisor</h4>
    <div class="introduction">Zubin is a bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla .</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.staff
{
margin-bottom:10px;
clear:both;}

.photo {
    padding-right: 5%;
    width:20%;
    float:left;
}
.intro {
    width: 60%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    padding-bottom:0px;
}
```

Now you can put a margin on the bottom of the containing divs.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2rj9u/1/

You might also wan't to look at using `display:inline-block` instead of floats: http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/.

On a side note don't use elements like `h4` purely for styling purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Where are  and  tags in your html?

```
 padding-botom
```

is the correct way of using. Not

```
 padding=bottom
```

. Try using this [CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/dhK6L/)

```
    .photo {
       padding-right: 0%; width:30%;  float: left;
       padding-top:20%;
       height:50% 
    }
```

Note: Using br tags for line spacing is a bad habit.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div display="block">
```

Add an id or class for this and  use css

```
id/class
{
 padding:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set am margin bottom for class photo

```
.photo {
padding-right: 5%; width:20%;  float: left; margin-bottom:40px;
}
```

as a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/parslook/Msxmp/

Answer (score 1):

I have created a fiddle for you. http://jsfiddle.net/RL4q9/2/
  have a look at this.

```
   .photo
   {
     padding-right: 0%; float: left;width:100px;
     padding-top:20%;;
   }
```

I hope you wanted to achieve this.Please vote.